# cqlsh returns "unsupported version of Python" error

Tags: cassandra

I'm using CentOS7 and Cassandra ver4.1
I have problem when cqlsh in cassandra not update my python version
when I insstalled Cassandra, I can not connect cqlsh with error

```
# cassandra/bin/cqlsh --version
Warning: unsupported version of Python: 2.7
No appropriate Python interpreter found.
```

So I install Python 3.8.16 and set it as default

```
# python -V
Python 3.8.16
```

But still connect to cqlsh with same error ( I restarted cassandra)

Can you tell me the solution to solve this issue

Thank you
Cuong

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an issue in your environment which is preventing cqlsh from finding the correct Python version.

Bash uses an internal hash table to make it faster to do `$PATH` lookups. When you install a new package on top of an existing package, sometimes Bash doesn't evict the old entry from the cache so continues to use the old entry.

Try to run this command to make Bash delete Python from it's hash table:

```
$ hash -d python
```

If that doesn't solve it for you, try deleting all versions of Python and start again. Cheers!

Comment: I just checked the configuration cqlsh, and tried to install python ver3.6. The warning disappears but still error "No appropriate Python interpreter found."

Comment: Because cqlsh can't find Python on your system as I explained. 

Comment: I found the reason, because I only add alias python so Cassandra can't detected. So I changed the default of python3 with alternatives. It worked